# Android - Update TextView on dialog dimiss listener

Tags: android, dialog, textview, refresh

I show a dialog where the user can enter a String value in an edittext and I want to display this value in an textview in the main layout after the dialog is dismissed. When the user clicks on the button "Ok" of the dialog, the textview is well refreshed, but I tried to do the same from the dismiss listener on the dialog it isn't, but I know the rest of the code is run. I tried to make it run on the mainthread but it didn't solve the problem. Here is the code, thanks for your help.

```
 final Dialog dialogStatus = new Dialog(Activity.this);
  dialogStatus.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);

  Button Bok = (Button) dialogStatus.findViewById(R.id.bt_dialog_ok);
  final EditText ETname = (EditText) dialogStatus.findViewById(R.id.et_dialog);

  Bok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          update(String.valueOf(ETname.getText()));
          dialogStatus.dismiss();
      }
  });
     dialogStatus.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

         @Override
         public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     update(String.valueOf(ETname.getText()));
                 }
             });
         }
     });
     dialogStatus.show();
 }

 public void update(String etValue){
     final SharedPreferences sharedPrefUnit = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, 0);
     SharedPreferences.Editor settings = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
             settings.putString(STRING_VALUE, etValue);
             TextView.setText(sharedPrefUnitScore.getString(STRING_VALUE, etValue, ""));

     settings.commit();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void update(String etValue){
    final SharedPreferences sharedPrefUnit = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor settings = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    settings.putString(STRING_VALUE, etValue);
    settings.commit();
    TextView.setText(etValue);
}
```

Because you were trying to get the value from shared preference before committing it.
If you won't commit it then it won't save.

Comment: Please give me green tick if it worked. Thank you...:)

Comment: Thanks It really help for me